# How to run a big loop in a Rails rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations, rake-task

I have a loop like the following a in Ruby on Rails rake task.

```
Account.all.each do |a|
```

The problem is that there are 10 million records and memory goes up uncontrollably. How could I segment that to run a big loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) that loads the record in batches.

Another approach is to just load the `IDs` and then fetch each record once.

I don't know what you are doing that requires loading your entire account table, but if it's a one-time task you have other possible alternatives such as using background jobs. If it's a recurring task or the result of a view, you may need to follow different approaches such as pagination.

Comment: I think find_each could work as it's a one time task being run in Screen.